# Play AudioBuffer in AVAudioEngine

Tags: swift, avaudioengine, audiobuffer

recently i encountered glitch sound when playing buffer with AURenderCallbackStruct. Therefore, i am trying another way to play the buffer.

Is there any method to play AudioBuffer with AVAudioEngine?

I have extract AudioStreamBasicDescription with ExtAudioFileRef, but seems like online tutorial is only provide a way to play with AVAudioPCMBuffer.

The reason of using ExtAudioFileRef to extract file is i need to take care of the audio file retrieve from MPMediaPlayer, not only bundle file.

Hope you all understand the context.
Appreciated if there is another way to stream audio buffer for bundle file and MpMediaPlayer file.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.